# как получить вектор от камеры на точку нажатия на экране?

Tags: математика, матрицы, opengl-3.3

На телефоне пользователь нажимает на экран.

у меня есть координаты нажатия на экран, размеры экрана, координаты камеры, вектор камеры, матрица Проекции и матрица Вида камеры для рисования 3D сцены на OpenGLES30.

как получить 3d Вектор от камеры на точку нажатия на экране?

Comment: А никак. Дело в том, что точке на экране соответствует вектор в пространстве. То есть, множество точек .

Comment: да, вы правы, и я об этом и спросил:) как найти этот вектор??? как его вычислить?

Comment: я бы рассмотрел на frustum (это срезанная пирамида) Очевидно, что плоскость экрана паралельна основаниям этой пирамиды, а выбранная точка на экране однозначно проецируется на оба основания. Теперь у нас есть две точки, можно строить вектор.

Comment: спасибо. Идея хорошая подумаю как это лучше сделать